# handle local software package in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have recently installed **docker 1.11.2 in fedora 22**, I am learning about docker file. I have 10+ software packages locally.

**My question is**

**what is the best way to handle that local file into docker**?

Comment: Do you mean by copying files from the host machine into the containers?

Comment: I am expecting best way to handle local software package so I am not specific the methods here. if you have advantage in your method please post your answer :-)

Comment: Just trying to get some facts right myself. So am I correct to say when you meant 'local' software packages they are essential packages sitting on your machine's file system? And they are not something you pull it off from another repository?

Comment: I have updated my question @SamuelToh please review that

Comment: This isn't really the forum for a basic tutorial - you would probably be best running through a few yourself and come back here when you run into problems and have specific questions. In regards to the Docker docs, did you start with https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/ ? If you don't like those Google has plenty more.

Comment: I understood @Idg I have updated my question please review. Actually I thought someone already handle the situation that is why I am not mention my stuff here because if I mention my stuff mostly try to solve my issue But I need to make sure about good practice of making docker file.

Comment: Thanks for the update question. Now this is even more confusing. Your initially question was around `DockerFile` and `building` images? The recent update suggests otherwise, seems like you are trying to create containers through images? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Idg ask my stuff that is why I am trying to mention. I am clearly told it I am not specific any method but I need best way to achieve this. your answer is seems ok I will work and come back to you.

Comment: Sure - Thank you. Glad to help. Remember, there is no best approach to things. Each method will have its own pros and cons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is still a bit confusing but supposedly you are trying to move packages into the container so that you could install them.

Then in this case you can specify the `ADD` and `RUN` keywords in the Dockerfile to get the job done.

**Example:**

```
# Copy package/files into the container
ADD debian_package1.deb ${MY_PATH}/
ADD debian_package2.deb ${MY_PATH}/

# Execute shell commands
RUN dpkg -i  ${MY_PATH}/debian_package1.deb
```

You may want to have a look at the documentation for DockerFile.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/